# Getting started with Dropwizard

Tags: java, eclipse, dropwizard

I am new to Dropwizard. This is also my first time to try to develop web service using Java. I have already started reading the "Getting Started" section in the dropwizard site.

However, I can't seem to figure out how to import the dropwizard classes starting with "com.yammer.dropwizard.config.Configuration"

What is the external archive/library that I need before I can use the dropwizard classes? The only file that I found is the downloadable from https://github.com/codahale/dropwizard, but this looks like source codes only. Anything I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: I am intending to use Maven. I am actually also looking for any maven-related library that I can include. I have checked and verified that I have Maven installed by default in my mac.

Comment: Then you want to include this dependency in your POM: http://dropwizard.codahale.com/getting-started/#setting-up-maven  After that, you should be right to go ...

Comment: I already have a POM file with that dependency. I haven't done anything related to Maven. Is there any initial setup that I need to do. What I have only done so far is added POM in my existing java project.

Comment: Have you developed Maven-built projects previously?  Do you have the m2e eclipse plugin installed?

Comment: No experience with Maven yet. I've only started working on Java again after more than 4 years.

Since I already have Maven in my system, can I proceed with installing the m2e eclipse plugin?

Comment: Install the m2e Eclipse plugin so that Eclipse is aware of Maven and will automatically add the Maven referenced libraries to the Eclipse classpath.

Comment: I'm doing it now. I can take it from here. Thanks for the help @GregKopff!

Comment: I have [written a few articles that may help you](http://gary-rowe.com/tags/Dropwizard/) when you start doing more advanced projects.

Comment: Hi! Thanks @GaryRowe. I'll look at those when I'm more comfortable with Dropwizard.

Comment: Hi again @GregKopff! I have successfully setup m2e plugin. Also, I can now import com.yammer.* packages. However, I still can't find com.yammer.dropwizard.config.Configuration. From the autocomplete I can see that there is com.yammer.dropwizard.config.*, but when I try to look for the Configuration class, it's not there. What should I do next?

Comment: What do you mean "look for it"? (The class is located in the `dropwizard-core` jar, but I don't really understand what your problem is / what you're asking)

Comment: I have created a class that extends the Configuration class. But in eclipse, the Configuration class is just underlined red. Additionally, I can do:

"import com.yammer.dropwizard.config.*;"

but not:

"import com.yammer.dropwizard.config.Configuration;"

Comment: Actually, this problem is the same for all dropwizard-core classes. I can import the packages, but I can't use the specific classes inside them.

Comment: Have you downloaded the repositories?

Answer (score 4):

Erwin,

if you would like to create your project using command-line interface, you could find the instructions [here](http://javaeeeee.blogspot.com/2015/01/getting-started-with-dropwizard-first.html).

On the other hand, if you would like to go with Eclipse, you should select File>Maven Project and in the dialog that appears press Next. In the next dialog press Add Archetype button.

[image]

In the dialog that appears

[image]

you should enter:

- groupId: io.dropwizard.archetypes
- artifactId: java-simple
- version:0.8.2

and press OK. Information about the current stable version can be obtained [here](https://dropwizard.github.io/dropwizard/getting-started.html).

After that you can try to type "drop" in Filter input field, select archetype from the list below and press Next.

[image]

In the following window set your projects Group Id, Artifact Id and don't forget to set the value of *name* parameter which is used in the names of autogenerated classes. After that press Finish.

[image]

A short youtube video is [here](https://youtu.be/r0t9EOtSspA).

Answer (score 0):

For com.yammer.dropwizard.config.Configuration, you require dropwizard-core jar. Just add that dependency of Jar, and you will be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
  <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
  <version>0.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And then going to your project directory and doing **mvn eclipse:eclipse**

You can also install something like the m2e plugin for Eclipse to have your project built automatically. If this doesn't work, you can try cleaning your project within eclipse going to **Project -> Clean**